# How do I change the port on which Pulsar is running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-pulsar

I want to run pulsar along with apache airflow. The catch is that both run on port number 8080. I do not want to change Airflow's configuration but in order to make pulsar run, I have to assign it another port. I am using a Python library, which runs airflow on 8080.

I tried going through the standalone installation document but could not get anything through it. My aim is to run the Python client of Pulsar.

How do I change the port configuration of Pulsar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For standalone, you can edit the `conf/standalone.conf` config file and set `webServicePort=8081`

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the `webservicePort` configuration in `conf/broker.conf`

Here's the github link: https://github.com/apache/pulsar/blob/master/conf/broker.conf

```
...
# Port to use to server HTTP request
webServicePort=8080

# Port to use to server HTTPS request - By default TLS is disabled
webServicePortTls=

# Hostname or IP address the service binds on, default is 0.0.0.0.
bindAddress=0.0.0.0
...
```